# How to fix this @mention regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to capture mentions to @usernames. Usernames have these rules:

- only lowercase letters, numbers or dots (.)
- not starting or ending with a dot
- no more than one dot in a row (e.g. user..name is not allowed, but us.er.name is)

So, I came up with this:

```
/(?:^|\s)(@)(?!\.)(?!.*\.\.)(?!.*\.[\s|$])([a-z0-9\.]+)(?:\s|$)/gm;
```

that should mean:

```
 (?:^|\s) starting at start of line, or with a whitespace
         (@) having a @
            (?!\.) name not starting with a dot
                  (?!.*\.\.) not containing two adjacent dots (..)
                            (?!.*\.[\s|$]) not ending with a dot (yes this sucks)
                                          ([a-z0-9\.]+) allowed chars
                                                       (?:\s|$) ending at EOL or whitespace
```

Being a complete noob with regexes, I was pretty happy to see how this performed with a long, multiline test string.
But then I tried the most simple test string, like:

```
@foo @bar I hate you both.
```

In this case foo is caught, but bar is not. I guess that, even if I use a non-capturing group, `@foo` takes also the following whitespace, so `@bar` fails at `(?:^|\s)`.

**How should I edit this regex to have it working?**

Please don’t suggest a completely different @mention regex, I can very well search for them as there are other questions. I’d just like to have this working, and to know why it doesn’t.

Comment: What do you want to happen to "@foo@bar"?

Comment: @Shawn no catch at all, there must be whitespace in between.

Comment: Your RegEx works perfectly if you use Lookbehind ([example](https://regex101.com/r/ypzKoJ/1)), but as I am sure you know Javascript does not support that. Best bet is to try and translate the lookbehind into lookahead and conditional statements.

Comment: There is an existing JavaScript library from Twitter to parse content like this: https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the issue you are having here is that you are using a capture group for the spaces at the beginning and end of a word, which means those characters are consumed from further RegEx matching.

This is because you do: `(?:...)`.

Instead you can use a special class of capture groups which does NOT consume the characters, called Lookahead: `(?=...)`

In RegEx, there is Lookbehind AND Lookahead, which checks before and after the RegEx respectively. The perfect answer to your question would use both lookbehind for the start of the string `(?<=^|\s)` and lookahead for the end of the string `(?=\s|$)`. Unfortunately, in Javascript, Lookbehind is not supported, but for your specific needs we can kind of get around that.

If we make sure NOT to capture the trailing space at the end of a username, then it can be used to match with the capture group you defined at the beginning of the RegEx. Here is that code:

```
(?:^|\s)(@)(?!\.)(?!\S*\.\.)(?!\S*\.[\s|$])([a-z0-9\.]+)(?=\s|$)
```

Note everything is nearly the same except for the '=' in the last section, and '\S' in the 'not ending with a dot' section and 'not containing two adjacent dots', which you caught below in the comments.

Results can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/ypzKoJ/5). Unfortunately, this returns the full match with the space in it for " @bar", but the subgroups of that match still look good.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I will look at it tomorrow, afk now. Should the condition "not ending with a dot" be rewritten now? Since trailing space is not captured anymore. I mean (?!.*\.[\s|$])

Comment: Good catch, you need to change that to `(?!\S*\.[\s|$])` where it will match any number of characters which are not a Space character, otherwise "@foo @bar." won't find any usernames. I will update my answer and example.

Comment: You will also need to update `(?!.*\.\.)` from "not containing two adjacent dots" to `(?!\S*\.\.)`

Answer (score 0):

This regexp will do the work:

```
@[0-9a-z](\.?[0-9a-z])*
```

as seen in the following [demo](https://regex101.com/r/LJOoTj/2).

Answer (score 0):

there are two types of mentions, with-space between like facebook and without-space like twitter:

for without space (like twitter):

```
(?:^|\\s|$|[.])@[\\p{L}0-9_]*
```

for with space (like facebook):

```
@[[\\p{L}0-9_]*(\\s)?[\\p{L}0-9_]*]*
```